# Set input value with Javascript on outside click

Tags: javascript, html, function, input

i want to set a max value to a number input. I used the "max" HTML attribute but the user can write a number over the max value anyway. Is there any way to reset the value of that input to the maximum value I set it, after the user sets it beyond the maximum value? Maybe when the user clicks outside that input?
Here is my code

```
<input type="number" name="days" id="days" min="1" max="365" value="<?php echo $ipq[0]['valueParam']?>">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to consider using a range control along with the value of the range being shown in a `span` element next to it. This way only the value range you specify is allowed (which is really what the range control is for).

```js
const output = document.getElementById("output");
document.getElementById("days").addEventListener("input", function(){
  output.textContent = this.value;
});
```

```html
<input type="range" name="days" id="days" min="1" max="365" value="1"><span id="output">1</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

The max attribute is validated on form submit. AS you can see in the snippet below the user will get a message when he tries to submit the form.

```html
<form>
<input type="number" name="days" id="days" min="1" max="365" value="366">
<input type='submit'>
</form>
```

If you want to prevent the user for inputting a value over 365 you can use js to do that. The snippet below shows how to prevent values over 365 for all number inputs.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('input[type="number"]').forEach((el) => el.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  let inputEl = e.currentTarget;
  if(parseFloat(inputEl.value) > parseFloat(inputEl.max)) {
    inputEl.value = inputEl.max;
  }  
}));
```

```html
<form>
<input type="number" name="days" id="days" min="1" max="365" value="366">
<input type='submit'>
</form>
```